# variable declaration in init statement of for loop

Tags: for-loop, go

Yet another beginner's question for golang:

I can write:

```
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {}
```

But if I want `i` to be of a specific type as `int64`, apparently I am not supposed to write:

```
for var i int64 = 0; i < 10; i++ {}
```

I am surprised that I cannot specify a type in the start statement of the for loop.  I need to write something like this:

```
var i int64
for i = 0; i < 10; i++ {}
```

Am I missing a point here? Is there any explanation for it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The language specification for a for loop states that: `The init statement may be a short variable declaration`, which is assignment of the form `i := 0` but not a declaration of the form `var i = 0`. As for the reason behind this - I'm guessing language simplicity. See here: http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements

BTW You *can* do something like this:

```
for  i := int64(0); i < 10; i++ {
   // i here is of type int64
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Go Language Specification: For statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) if you choose the form of the `ForClause`:

```
ForClause = [ InitStmt ] ";" [ Condition ] ";" [ PostStmt ] .
```

The definition of the `InitStmt`:

```
SimpleStmt = EmptyStmt | ExpressionStmt | SendStmt | IncDecStmt | Assignment
               | ShortVarDecl .
```

So as you can see if you want to create a new variable in the `for` statement, it can only be a [Short Variable declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#ShortVarDecl), like this:

```
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {}
```

The Short variable declaration can be used to declare new variables of any types, and the types of the variables will be the types of of the corresponding initialization values on the right side.

Let's examine it a little bit closer:

```
i := 0
```

On the right side there is `0`: it is an untyped numeric constant. Note that untyped consants in Go have a *default* type which is used if a type is needed, like this case. The default type of an untyped integer consant is `int` hence the variable `i` will have `int` type.

If you want it to have the type `int64`, use an expression which has `int64` type, like these:

```
for i := int64(0); i < 10; i++ {} // Explicit type conversion

const ZERO int64 = 0
for i := ZERO; i < 10; i++ {}     // Typed constant

var vzero int64

for i: = vzero; i < 10; i++ {}    // Expression of type int64
```

Or create the `i` variable before the `for` statement using `var` declaration:

```
var i int64
for i = 0; i < 10; i++ {}         // Variable is declared before for using "var"
```

Note that this last example does not use the Short Variable declaration just a simple assignment.